# Loop over a string variable in R

Tags: r

I would like to loop over a string variable. For example:

```
clist <- c("BMI", "trig", "hdl")

for (i in clist) {
 data_FK_i<-subset(data_FK, subset= !is.na(FK) & (!is.na(i)))
}
```

The "i" should receive a different name from the list.
What am I doing wrong? It's not working? Adding "" doesn't seem to help.

Thank,

Einat

Thanks, the "assign" answer did the work!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this instead, which will give you a list containing the three subsetted dataframes:

```
lapply(clist, function(x) data_FK[ !is.na(data_FK$FK) & !is.na(data_FK[,x]) ,])
```

The problem in your code is that `i` is a character string, specifically one of the values from `clist` in each iteration of the `for`-loop. So, when R reads `!is.na(i)` you're saying `!is.na("BMI")`, etc.

Various places on Stack Overflow advise against using `subset` at all in favor of extraction indices (i.e., `[`) like in the example code above because `subset` relies on [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) that is confusing and sometimes leads you down bad rabbit holes.

Comment: I suppose you want `&` instead of `&&`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein Indeed. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Thomas. You should use a list. However, let me demonstrate how to modify your code to create multiple objects. You can use the function `assign` to create objects based on strings.

```
clist <- c("BMI", "trig", "hdl")

for (i in clist) {
 assign(paste0("data_FK_", i), complete.cases(data[c("FK", i)]))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

You need to give the loop something to store the data into.
Also you need to tell the loop how long you want it to run.

```
clist <- c("BMI", "trig", "hdl")

#empty vector
data_FK<-c()

#I want a loop and it will 'loop' 3 times (1 to 3), which is the length of my list
for (i in 1:length(clist)) {
  #each loop stores the corresponding item from the list into the vector
  data_FK<-c(data_FK,clist[i])
}

## or if you want to store the values in a data frame
## there are other ways to create this, but here is a simple solution
data_FK<-data.frame(placer=1:length(clist))

for(i in 1:length(clist)){
  data_FK$items[i]<-clist[i]
}

## or maybe you just want to print the names
for (i in 1:length(clist)){
   print(clist[i])
}
```